# Is there a way to tell if a File reference is unique in the JVM instance?

Tags: java, file, unique

My situation is that I'm loading files from a data source. I want to throw an error if the same file is referenced twice.

Here is an unsafe implementation demo to illustrate the idea:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a.txt", "b.txt", "a.txt");

    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

    for(String fileString: strings) {
        files.add(new File(fileString));
    }
}
```

Now the simplest way to solve this is to use a set on the absolute file path:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a.txt", "b.txt", "a.txt");

    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

    Set<String> fileSet = new HashSet<String>();

    for(String fileString: strings) {
        File file = new File(fileString);
        boolean unique = fileSet.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (unique)
            files.add(new File(fileString));
    }
}
```

Is there a way that the JVM saves me from having to implement this? Here is a rough sketch of a method `isUnique` I wish existed on the file API:

```
public static void main3(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a.txt", "b.txt", "a.txt");

    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

    for(String fileString: strings) {
        File file = new File(fileString);

        boolean unique = file.isUnique();
        if (unique)
            files.add(new File(fileString));
    }
}
```

My question is: **Is there a way to tell if a File reference is unique in the JVM instance?**

Comment: Doubt it. Also, bear in mind [hard links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

I don't even think you can use any reflection API to get all File references and do the check yourself. I'd just use the absolute file path as you suggest.